# How to overlap in Relative Layout Android Studio

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to send the white image in the back of my button and text in Relative Layout. Here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.sahni.lightspeed.starting_screen"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_starting_screen"
android:background="@drawable/q1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textSize="70sp"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:textColor="#00e1ff"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/start_button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:background="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout sets for the image aren't correct, but I don't know which ones to use to get the output I want. A screenshot of current output:

[image]

- Am I using the best layout for this problem ?
- Can someone please explain to me how the solution works too?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more!,
We are not getting it, what you want!

Comment: @AkashDubey I'm trying to get the `ImageView` to be behind the `TextView` and `Button`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move to first `ImageView` in your `RelativeLayout` :

```
<RelativeLayout ... >
     <ImageView ... />
     <TextView ... />
     <Button ... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Your `ImageView` has `android:layout_below="@+id/title"` property so it' always below your title, so it can't be in background of your title.

Comment: It sorts overlapping by seeing what is the order of objects in the code?

Comment: yes that's it, order in layout, set visibility order (background to foreground)

Comment: I tried to do this;  I put  my spinner code underneath my button code, so that my spinner appears on top of the button, however the button is still on top.